# Sending email from ASP.NET MVC web app not working after deployment on GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-hosting, smtpclient, godaddy-api

I have created an ASP.NET MVC application using C# in Visual Studio 2022. In it, I have implemented email functionality using SMTP. The email functionality works perfectly fine in local, but as we deploy to our Godaddy server, it does not work anymore - it neither sends any mail, nor does it show any errors.

Here is my code:

`web.config`:

```
<add key="Port" value="25"/>
<add key="Host" value="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"/>
<add key="FromEmail" value="senderemail@gmail.com"/>
<add key="FromPassword" value="senderpassword"/>
<add key="ToEmail" value="reciveremail@gmail.com"/>
<add key="IsSSL" value="false" />
```

C# code in controller method:

```
MailMessage _mailmsg = new MailMessage();
_mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
_mailmsg.From = new MailAddress(emailSender);
_mailmsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ToEmail));
_mailmsg.Subject = "Test Mail";
_mailmsg.Body = "Body";

SmtpClient _smtp = new SmtpClient();
_smtp.Host = emailSenderHost;
_smtp.EnableSsl = emailIsSSL;
_smtp.Port = emailSenderPort;
_smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

NetworkCredential _network = new NetworkCredential(emailSender, emailSenderPassword); // credetials of google gmail account
_smtp.Credentials = _network;
_smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

try
{
    _smtp.Send(_mailmsg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    return false;
}
return true
```

If anyone has faced this issue in the past, or has any suggestions to solve this issue, please provide answer as I have already spent a couple of days trying to resolve this issue.

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @marc_s, it was just typo, I have corrected it. It is not the cause of error.

Comment: I don't know about GoDaddy - but all my servers use `SSL=true`. I also noticed that with SSL port 465 (rather than 25) works better. Worth trying. Finally, I usually test as command-line application - if it doesn't run, it always throws some error (and you don't need catch block)

Comment: @Felix, I have tried that but it is not working.

Comment: @prog1011 Please kindly ask Godaddy support what settings that you need to use.